# How to re-arrange NSString characters?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have one NSString,

```
11/17/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to make it like

```
17/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to swipe Day with Month,

I was trying to do by subString, but can't get exact idea.

There is a way to convert to NSData and change format, but I would prefer to do via NSString.

Thanks

Comment: How about using `substringWithRange:` and `appendString:`? Unfortunately, you'll need to **read the documentation** and **attempt something yourself.** With methods like the ones I've just pointed out, this should be trivial.

Comment: Why don't you use the DateFormatter, That will be much more efficient.

Comment: No, you would *not* prefer to do it via NSString, it's just one more way to shoot yourself in the foot. If you deal with a date, then well, deal with a date, not a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
id temp = [array objectAtIndex:1];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:temp];

NSString * finalString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
```

Comment: You'll need a mutable array to `replaceObjectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Yes you are right. My fault.

Comment: Yes, i did it dear by mutable, let me test

Comment: @NikosM. No problem. However, `componentsSeparateByString:` still returns an immutable array.

Comment: Thats a compiler warning, but edited my answer so it is completely correct. Thanks @H2CO3

Comment: @NikosM. It's a compiler warning **and a runtime exception**.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe downvoted an edited answer that actually works?

Comment: @NikosM. Can't downvote the comment (which makes it sound like it was correct before the edit).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe your comment is not correct. It does not cause runtime exception. You can try the code without mutableCopy and test it. But as mentioned, I cannot downvote a comment.

Comment: @nikosm unfortunately, you're not right. `mutableCopy` is necessary, and the compiler warning was there for a reason. Maybe `componentsSeparatedBySring` itself returns a mutable array, but that's an implementation detail which you shan't rely upon. It's documented to return an immutable array, so you always have to treat it as such. "It worked" is a logical fallacy if abused as a proof.

Comment: @H2CO3 just tested this code:  `NSMutableArray *array = [@"11/17/2013 12:00:00 AM" componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    id temp = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:temp];
    
    NSString * finalString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    NSLog(@"Final String %@", finalString);` in xcode 5 and the output is `Final String 17/11/2013 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: @NikosM. I know and believe it worked without the copy. Read my (now more verbose) comment. It only worked because you were lucky.

Comment: @H2CO3 I totally agree with you, but from "it works but it is not the correct implementation" to "it causes a runtime exception" written in bold  is miles away. (I think with a runtime exception the person who asked the question wouldn't have chosen this answer.)

Comment: @NikosM. I'd remove the downvote because the question in itself is not wrong any more (It's locked in, though). The reasoning in your comments is very wrong, as H2CO3 pointed out. It's a beginner's mistake to take a "It works" for a proof of validity.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe you are right, but that does not mean that a senior should make the same mistake from the opposite side: seeing definite crashes where at least they are not definite.

Comment: @NikosM. Certainly he wouldn't, but that's not the point (which you don't quite seem to get anyway). It could have indeed thrown a runtime error; in fact, it's possible that it does so for some implementations. So Nikolai's comment is not "miles away" from the truth. He didn't "make the same mistake" -- in programming, programs must be perfect to be reliable, so it's not enough that something "works" -- there must be solid logical reasoning a to *why* it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try It:

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[@"11/17/2013 12:00:00 AM" componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy];
[dateArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:1 withObjectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dateString = [dateArray componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
NSString *date = @"11/17/2013 12:00:00 AM";
NSString *m = [date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
NSString *d = [date substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/2013 12:00:00 AM",d,m];
```

I haven't tested it